# Tags in app & legal content

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android and I want to ask u a few questions:

1: Is there any tag that will make my app easier to be find in Google market when it will be searched ( like meta tags in html) ?

2: I've created a math application in my native language. I couldn't find on market any other apps that looks similar or that are in the same language, but I found many others in English or other languages.

Is it legal to put my app on Google market ?

I've searched on Google developers but  didn't find anything about this. If u can give me a link from Google it would be great. Also, can I put my name on the bottom of my app?

And the last question I have, is it any way to earn money from free apps without using adds?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: It;s not about legal advice, I just couldn't find the terms of google :D Solved it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can do some research on the subject of Google Play SEO:

- [10 Tips on SEO for Your Apps Position in Google Play](http://www.techlitic.com/10-tips-on-seo-for-your-apps-position-in-google-play.html)
- [Google I/O 2013 - Getting Discovered on Google Play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Od2SuL2igA)

But there's no "secret formula" of any kind. Also, remember that just "dumping" keywords in your app page's description is not permitted.

As for the second question, I don't really see any reason for the app not to be legal if you coded it yourself, it isn't' a blatant copy of some one else's app and obeys [Google Play's content policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html).